# Maintain list order removing and adding elements

Tags: c#

I am having trouble coming up with the logic for this problem. I have a list of items that are displayed in a window. If an item is in the list it is displayed. I have no way of changing this. I am accessing the list through a inherited class that I may edit. I cannot edit the source code of the base class in any way (the class containing the list). The class I am editing is the class that is inserted into the list. It also has access to the list.

I need to be able to remove items from the list and insert them while maintaining the same order.

Example if my list is:

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

I remove 2,3,4 I then have

```
1,5
```

But then I add 4,3,2 back in that order. It must display

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

again and not

```
1,4,3,2,5
```

They must be in the original order that they were removed in. This is just a example these values cannot be sorted. They are in the order they were added in.

So the question is, how can I remove and add elements into a list and make sure that the order is kept?

I have tried:

Inserting null values instead of removing elements from the list. This does not work as a blank spot is displayed. I have also tried remember the index that they were removed at but when I insert them back into the list multiple items may be inserted back at index 0 and lose the ordering because the list has shrunk.

I am using a ObservableCollection http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx

I hope this post is clear in what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: If you need to preserve the original order of a collection which is not itself inherently ordered (e.g. sorted list), then the right way to "remove" elements is actually to create a filtered copy of the collection with the unwanted elements removed. Alternatively, you will have to keep a separate data structure tracking what was removed from where, so you can reverse the order putting them back in.

Comment: Have you tried to use `SortedList`?

Comment: Specify what you mean with "it must diplay". If it's just for display  purposes provide a method which returns the sorted items. You can do it easily: `string.Join(",", list.OrderBy(x => x))`

Comment: When adding an item to the list are they simply added at the end? And what if I have `{ 1, 2, 3 }` and I then add a second `2`? Does it appear at the end or as `{ 1, 2, 2, 3 }`?

Comment: how about showing us some code so that we can understand what type of list that you are using.. also adding removing Items from a List<T> is not that difficult if you are talking about adding and removing from something like a ListBox then that's a different story also do some basic `Googling`

Comment: @L.B as I mentioned I cannot edit the base class that contains the list. It is a ObservableCollection, I have no choice in this.

Comment: Also I should not have used numbers. The list is not and cannot be sorted it is a complex class. They do not need to be sorted. Just maintain the order they appeared in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea for you. I've implemented my own `IList<T>` class that does what you want (I think.)

First I started with this:

```
public class RememberOrderList<T> : IList<T>
{
}
```

I've then created an `_inner` list of `T` and implemented most of the required methods by passing through to `_inner`.

```
public class RememberOrderList<T> : IList<T>
{
    private List<T> _inner = new List<T>();
    public int IndexOf(T item) { return _inner.IndexOf(item); }
    public void RemoveAt(int index) { _inner.RemoveAt(index); }
    public T this[int index] { get { return _inner[index]; } set { _inner[index] = value; } }
    public void Clear() { _inner.Clear(); }
    public bool Contains(T item) { return _inner.Contains(item); }
    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex) { _inner.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex); }
    public int Count { get { return _inner.Count; } }
    public bool IsReadOnly { get { return ((ICollection<T>)_inner).IsReadOnly; } }
    public bool Remove(T item) { return _inner.Remove(item); }
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() { return _inner.GetEnumerator(); }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return _inner.GetEnumerator(); }
```

Now, there are two methods that add items to the list - `Insert` & `Add`.

`Insert` is a problem as it specifies the index and we don't want that - so that will throw a `NotSupportedException`.

```
    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
```

`Add` just needs to remember the order of items as they are added and do a sort before exiting. That requires a little more work.

To keep track of the order of items I'm using a `Dictionary<T, int>`.

```
    private readonly Dictionary<T, int> _order = new Dictionary<T, int>();
```

And to sort a `List<T>` you need a `IComparer<T>`.

```
    private class OrderComparer : IComparer<T>
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<T, int> _order;
        public OrderComparer(Dictionary<T, int> order)
        {
            _order = order;
        }

        public int Compare(T x, T y)
        {
            return _order[x].CompareTo(_order[y]);
        }
    }
```

Now `Add` is easy.

```
    public void Add(T item)
    {
        if (!_order.ContainsKey(item))
        {
            _order[item] = _order.Count;
        }
        _inner.Add(item);
        _inner.Sort(new OrderComparer(_order));
    }
```

Putting that all together allows me to do this:

```
var rol = new RememberOrderList<int>();

rol.Add(1);
rol.Add(2);
rol.Add(3);
rol.Add(4);
rol.Add(5);

rol.Remove(2);
rol.Remove(3);
rol.Remove(4);

rol.Add(4);
rol.Add(3);
rol.Add(2);
```

From which I get this list:

[image: Result]

Now, just to avoid any confusion, I ran this code again using `20` in place of `2` and got the result `{ 1, 20, 3, 4, 5 }` so it is sorting by the desired behaviour.